# How to correctly query parent & child documents in SOLR?

Tags: search, indexing, solr, lucene

**Index Structure:**

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "doc_type": [
        "dataset"
      ],
      "title": [
        "document_title"
      ],
      "id": [
        1234
      ],
      "_childDocuments_": [
        {
          "parent_id": [
            1234
          ],
          "doc_type": [
            "column"
          ],
          "id": [
            789
          ],
          "attr_nm": [
            "child_field_value"
          ],
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Whenever a search/query is performed I always want to return the parent document. E.g. If I search for 'child_field_value' I want to get the parent document ad the child documents are never seen by the user.

I can get this working for parents. E.g. if I search for 'document_title' I can get the structure above using the following setup:

```
q=document_title
fl=*,[child parentFilter=doc_type:dataset]
qf=title^200 attr_nm
```

If I try this using the query keyword "child_field_value" I get a strange structure like:

```
"response": {
  "numFound":2,
  "start":0,
  "docs":[
    {
      "parent_id":"1234",
      "doc_type":"column",
      "id":"123",
      "attr_nm":"child_field_value",
    },
    {
      "parent_id":"1234",
      "doc_type":"column",
      "id":"456",
      "attr_nm":"child_field_value",
      "_childDocuments_":[{
        "parent_id":"1234",
        "doc_type":"column",
        "id":"124",
        "attr_nm":"child_field_value",
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I ensure always get the desired results even if searching a child field for any value?